# Closing a JTable Instance

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a java application that uses a jtabe to allow the user to capture data. This data would be written to a text  file later. The application is working fine. Good. However, I wanted to add a button such that when a user click this button, the application should first ask the user to save(writing to a text file) and after this the application should **close the table(terminating the the table instance from the memory) -more of closing a Word Document.**  My table is sitting on panel.

How do I perform this? I need the **closing (a sort of myTable.close() - to errase data in the table)** part only,everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your table the UI using [Container.remove(yourTable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) and ensure you have no references to the table or the TableModel.  Garbage collection will take care of the rest.

There used to be an issue where any listeners added would stop your UI component being collection but I'm unsure if this is still the case, and may have been limited to just inner classes being used for the Listener.

Comment: It worked perfect. Someone recommended me to use `dispose` - is there any special differences between the two regarding clearing the containers?

Comment: `JTable` doesn't have a `dispose()` method.  `dispose()` is defined by `Window` and will remove all child components.